# Spark session with hivecontext

Tags: apache-spark

I tried to use `Sparksession` with hive tables.

I had used the following code:

```
val spark= SparkSession.builder().appName("spark").master("local").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()  

spark.sql("select * from data").show()
```

Shows table not found, but the table exists in hive. Please help me with this.

Comment: Did you added hive-site.xml in spark conf?

Answer (score 2):

spark.sql("select * from databasename.data").show() - will work

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have to provide the path of warehouse, like:

```
// warehouseLocation points to the default location for managed databases and tables
val warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark Hive Example")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

For more information, You can see here: [Hive Tables with Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables)

Comment: This does not work. It will use the same local spark warehouse path.