# Not able to connect SparkSession to Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am getting data from .csv files and then registering the df as TempView.
After that I am trying to write the contents from TempView to Hive tables.
However I'm getting error that the database is not found. But I do have the database in hive.

Below is the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col


object read_data {


  def main (args:Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
      .config("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
      .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "user/hive/warehouse")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

    ///val hiveContext =  new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(spark);


    val customSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("order_id", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("parent_order_uuid", StringType, true),
      StructField("company", StringType, true),
      StructField("country_id", IntegerType, true)))

    val readogp = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "false")
      .schema(customSchema)
      .load("/home/cloudera/Desktop/ogp_csv.csv")

   // readogp.createOrReplaceTempView("OGP_INTL")

    val read_country = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .load("/home/cloudera/Desktop/country.csv")


    //read_country.createOrReplaceTempView("Dim_Country")
      println("************************************************************************")


    val rept = readogp.join(read_country, readogp("country_id") === read_country("country_id"),"inner")

    val final_rp = rept.select(col("order_id"), col("country_iso_code_2"))
      .groupBy("country_iso_code_2")
      .sum("order_id")
      .orderBy("country_iso_code_2")

      final_rp.createOrReplaceTempView("FINAL_REPORT_OGP")


    spark.sql("use ods")
    spark.sql("""insert into ods.final_ogp
       select * from FINAL_REPORT_OGP""")

  }

}
```

Error Log:

```
18/10/13 13:01:56 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_database: ods
18/10/13 13:01:56 INFO audit: ugi=cloudera  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: ods   
18/10/13 13:01:56 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database ods, returning NoSuchObjectException
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchDatabaseException: Database 'ods' not found;
```

The database ods does exist in Hive and so does the table. Have I made a mistake in the code?

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you need `use ods` ?

Comment: ods is my database in hive. It has the tables final_ogp.

Comment: I tried adding the warehouse location as suggested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177141/spark-session-with-hivecontext but same issue. Its not taking the hive warehouse location

Comment: @Bala Any ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access existing table in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862659/how-to-access-existing-table-in-hive)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can  would check is the value of spark conf `spark.sql.catalogImplementation`, it should be set to *hive*.

This could be found from Spark UI(in local mode it should be accessible at http://localhost:4040 by default) .
The call to `enableHiveSupport` when creating the SparkSession, sets the above mentioned conf and Spark thereafter uses HiveCatalog.
If the value of the conf is *in-memory*, then Spark's in-memory catalog is used.

I see the following implementation for `enableHiveSupport`,

```
def enableHiveSupport(): Builder = synchronized {
      if (hiveClassesArePresent) {
        config(CATALOG_IMPLEMENTATION.key, "hive")
      } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because " +
            "Hive classes are not found.")
      }
    }




  private[spark] def hiveClassesArePresent: Boolean = {
    try {
      Utils.classForName(HIVE_SESSION_STATE_BUILDER_CLASS_NAME)
      Utils.classForName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf")
      true
    } catch {
      case _: ClassNotFoundException | _: NoClassDefFoundError => false
    }
  }
```

From the above snippets, it might be that the driver classpath is not set rightly to include `org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf`

Answer (score 0):

The program certainly is not able to connect to the Hive warehouse, seems you gave wrong warehouse path. Please correct path: "user/hive/warehouse"
I think it would be: "**/user/hive/warehouse**" (Absolute path)

Also another check: you would get this issue, if you are running your program from Intellij (per se any editor). If yes, add the hive-site.xml in your project resources: /src/main/resources
Also you would need to add the jars, Ex: Hive JDBC, mySQL connector (if MySQL metastore).

Hope it helps.